# Array is not passed on to next() method while making iterator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iterator

I am teaching myself coding, learning Java Script.  I am working on a problem from a book where I need to make an iterator for a custom object, which acts like a Set.

When I want to access the array I have set up to hold the data in the next() method, I get the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at Object.next (testerBook.js:34)
at testerBook.js:83

Within the next() method, it has the array as undefined.

Code is as follows:

```js
class Group {
  constructor() {
    this.values = [];
  }

  add(value) {
    if (!this.values.includes(value)) {
      this.values.push(value);
    }
  }

  delete(value) {
    if (this.values.includes(value)) {
      this.values = this.values.filter(e => e !== value);
    }
  }

  has(value) {
    return this.values.includes(value);
  }

  [Symbol.iterator]() {

    let count = 0;
    let nvalues = this.values;
    console.log('nvalues is ', nvalues);

    return {
      next() {
        console.log('In next in iterator ', this.nvalues);
        //try the ++ count afterwards
        if (count === this.values.length - 1) {
          return {
            value: undefined,
            done: true
          };
        } else {
          count++;
          return {
            value: this.values[count - 1],
            done: false
          };
        }

      }
    }
  }

  static from(newValues) {
    let group = new Group();
    for (let value of newValues) {
      if (!group.has(value)) {
        group.add(value);
      }
    }
    return group;
  }

}


let group = Group.from([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5]);
console.log(group.values);
for (let value of group) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

I'm hoping it is something easy that I dont see.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you include a fully reproducible example with the code that instantiates and calls and uses the object?

Comment: `this` is not the `Group` object inside the `next()` method.

Comment: I have added  the full code in an edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is not being passed into the `next` function. You can pass it in implicitly using an arrow function.

Also the iterator ends early, change `if (count === this.values.length - 1) {` to `if (count === this.values.length) {`

```js
class Group {
    constructor() {
        this.values = [];
    }

    add(value) {
        if (!this.values.includes(value)) {
            this.values.push(value);
        }
    }

    delete(value) {
        if (this.values.includes(value)) {
            this.values = this.values.filter(e => e !== value);
        }
    }

    has(value) {
        return this.values.includes(value);
    }

    [Symbol.iterator]() {
        
        let count = 0;
        let nvalues = this.values;
        console.log('nvalues is ', nvalues);

        return {
            next: () => {
                console.log('In next in iterator ', JSON.stringify(this,null,2));
                //try the ++ count afterwards
                if (count === this.values.length) {
                    return { value: undefined, done: true };
                } else {
                    count++;
                    return { value: this.values[count - 1], done: false };
                }

            }
        }
    }
    
    static from(newValues) {
      let group = new Group();
      for (let value of newValues) {
        if (!group.has(value)) {
          group.add(value);
        }
      }
      return group;
    }
}

let group = Group.from([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5]);
console.log(group.values);
for (let value of group) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'll do some more reading on how this works with arrow functions, and regular function();

Answer (score 0):

`this` is not captured in traditional closures.

You can use the `nvalues` local variable, just like you do with `count`.

```js
class Group {
  constructor() {
    this.values = [];
  }

  add(value) {
    if (!this.values.includes(value)) {
      this.values.push(value);
    }
  }

  delete(value) {
    if (this.values.includes(value)) {
      this.values = this.values.filter(e => e !== value);
    }
  }

  has(value) {
    return this.values.includes(value);
  }

  [Symbol.iterator]() {

    let count = 0;
    let nvalues = this.values;
    console.log('nvalues is ', nvalues);

    return {
      next() {
        console.log('In next in iterator ', this.nvalues);
        //try the ++ count afterwards
        if (count === nvalues.length - 1) {
          return {
            value: undefined,
            done: true
          };
        } else {
          count++;
          return {
            value: nvalues[count - 1],
            done: false
          };
        }

      }
    }
  }

  static from(newValues) {
    let group = new Group();
    for (let value of newValues) {
      if (!group.has(value)) {
        group.add(value);
      }
    }
    return group;
  }

}


let group = Group.from([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5]);
console.log(group.values);
for (let value of group) {
  console.log(value);
}
```